# From when did people started assuming a principal bundle is locally trivial?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, principal-bundles

Question is as in the title:

> From when did people started assuming a principal bundle is locally trivial?

I am asking this because, Dale Husemoller in his book "Fibre bundles" (1966) defines "locally trivial principal bundle". Now, I do not see any mention of "locally trivial principal bundle". A principal bundle is always assumed to be locally trivial.

Comment: A principal bundle is a particular case of fiber bundles. In the definition of fiber bundles, it is asked to be locally trivial.

Comment: @DIdier_ Not in Husemollers "Fibre bundles" book..

Comment: Yes, language uses changes. In Chern's papers of the 1950's, the term *exact* was used for *closed* differential forms. How's that for confusing? The difference between fibration and fiber bundle may have caused some language issues, and maybe that's why Husemoller was emphasizing things. I no longer have Steenrod's book, sadly.

Comment: @TedShifrin :D That is already too much... I could not guess the difficulty of people who are learning those for the first time in 1950's.. :D